# Calculating multiplier based on distance between 2 numbers

Tags: python, math, formulas

I'm not sure how to word the question correctly but I'll try.

I'm trying to find a formula to provide a multiplier based on the difference between 2 integers.

#### Examples

- 1 and 1 = distance is 0  = 1
- 1 and 2 = distance is +1 = 1.5
- 1 and 3 = distance is +2 = 1.75
- 1 and 4 = distance is +3 = 1.89
- 1 and 5 = distance is +4 = 1.95
- 1 and 6+ = distance is +5 = 2.0
- 20 and 21 = distance is +1 = 1.5

I need this to work for negative distances too.

- 2 and 1 = distance is -1 = 0.5
- 3 and 1 = distance is -2 = 0.75

all the multipliers I used above are examples.

I'm trying to implement this in Python so any sort of example in python would be ideal.

#### **Thanks** to Pedro, John Moeller and ayhan I have this:

```
from math import sqrt

def multiplier(x, y):
    dist = y - x
    return 1 + dist/sqrt(5+dist**2)
```

This gives the output:

```
Distance: -5 = 0.09
Distance: -4 = 0.13
Distance: -3 = 0.20
Distance: -2 = 0.33
Distance: -1 = 0.59
Distance: 0 = 1.00
Distance: 1 = 1.41
Distance: 2 = 1.67
Distance: 3 = 1.80
Distance: 4 = 1.87
Distance: 5 = 1.91
```

Close enough, Thanks!

Comment: Do you have _any_ code you want to show us to demonstrate what you've tried?

Comment: added. I know it works but its too tragic to show anyone.

Comment: What does the multiplier have to do with the graph? What is the value of the multiplier if the difference is 0?

Comment: the graph just kinda shows the trend, If the difference is 0 then the multiplier should be 1.

Comment: Wait, is the multiplier just 1 plus the corresponding value of the graph? Why not just use `d = x - y; return 1+d/sqrt(5+d^2)`??

Comment: So you have a set of rules in mind, and you are trying to find a function that follows those rules (approximately maybe)?

Comment: exactly, the multiplier should get closer to X2 all the ways up to a difference of 5, then it caps at X2. the values I used are not set in stone.

Comment: All of your examples involve integer inputs.  Can we assume the inputs are always integers?

Comment: input will always be integers

Comment: You can play with the constant term and the degree. For example, `return 1 + dist/sqrt(3+dist**2)` would approach 2 more slowly but will have closer values for dist = 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try: 1 + x/sqrt(1+x^2).
This gives a trend like the one from your graph but it's y limits are 0 and 2, and x=0 gives y=1 as required.

http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+%2B+x%2Fsqrt%281%2Bx%5E2%29&x=0&y=0

In Python:

```
import math 
def multiplier(x, y):
    dist = x - y
    return 1 + dist/math.sqrt(1+dist**2)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I suggested in my comment to the OP.

Comment: I did not see your comment, sorry, but also, mine is different because it's not got a 5 in the bracket.

Comment: I think the graph seems to be causing confusion. I'll remove it.
The graph is only there to show the trend.

Comment: Yeh but with the function I gave you it will give you the correct trend. Just write that in Python. If the distance (x) is 5, then the multiplier will be 1.98 using my function . if that is not good enough you could manually set it to 2 for values above 5. A long series of if-else statements like the one you have is probably not the way to go.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but this function seems to be spitting out divide by zero and math domain errors. again Thank you for the help.

Comment: Have you got the right imports? I'll edit my solution.

Comment: I couldn't edit just for one character but you should have `dist**2` instead of `dist^2`. `^`  is the XOR operator in Python.